# MetaMask app/browser SSL Error (local server HTTPS testing)

Tags: metamask, testing, error, browsers

Creating a dApp using Vite; within the config file I've imported mkcert to produce SSL certs.

I've also installed these on my mobile device. I have no issues at all using the website/dApp in Chrome (both my mobile device or my computer) where any warnings or errors have been resolved.

However MetaMask mobile is still pushing back with "SSL error: This certificate authority is not trusted".

I've tried a number of ways of obtaining SSL certs but MetaMask is proving very inflexible compared to everything else, which is a problem because ideally it's one of the more important environments to test my dApp in.

Does anyone have any advice on how to push through this?

thanksInAdv!